# Font Color,Size,font change

Tags: asp.net

i have one template for that i am not creating any CSS File through one form we are adding the font style,font,font size and we are storing that in database that stored database information i want to apply for my pages dynamically depending on the template selection we are update the pages.how it is possible

Comment: What is stored? The site? The colors? What format? Stylesheets? Give more info please.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more information, but i suspect that you fixed your values that you created dynamically and stored it in database. For that you will need overwrite your css rules after retrieving them. In future you should try to dynamically give only class name and after change only that css class.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically create CSS rules.